# Umbraco: Check if page is marked as protected and redirect to login

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

In my DocType i have a property by the name of "membersOnly" (true/false).

When checked, I want to check, if the user is logged in, if not, redirect to login page with a referrer.

But what is the best way to do this - I dont want to have it in my Master template. How can I hook into the request pipeline, check if the "membersOnly" field excist, and if it does, and it is checked, and the user is not logged in, redirect the user?

Any short snippets out there?

Also, I am aware of the built-in Umbraco way of doing this. But for this case, i need it to be just a simple checkbox on the page in the backend - but the functionality that it fires, is basicly the same, as if i used the built-in Umbraco way in the backend.

Comment: I actually think it would be easier to just do it the built-in way :-/ But you could always check the Umbraco source code and see how they do it, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using route hijacking then checking authentication through your controllers. However, if all you have to do is check for authentication, it might be a little bit of an overkill to do route hijacking for your doc types.

Essentially, to do route hijacking, you create a controller with the same name as your doctype, so if your doctype is "memberPage", your controller would look like this:

```
public class MemberPageController : RenderMvcController
{
    public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        return base.Index(model);
    }
}
```

Notice how it must inherit RenderMvcController in order to work.

Before returning the base RenderMvcController method "Index", you can now run code, e.g. to check authentication.

So you could do this:

```
    public ActionResult Index(RenderModel model)
    {
        if (Members.IsLoggedIn())
        {
            return base.Index(model);
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to implement this yourself, would probably be by creating a custom filter derived from `Authorization​Filter​Attribute` (located in `System.​Web.​Http.​Filters`).

Having the derived object use the umbracocontext and query the settings based on the current page.

Umbraco does exactly the same for their custom validation, for some inspiration check out [MemberAuthorizeAttribute at github](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/7ee510ed386495120666a78c61497f58ff05de8f/src/Umbraco.Web/WebApi/MemberAuthorizeAttribute.cs)